# SQL Query with Sessions

Tags: mysql, session

Hi I have a SQL Query that I had working but now as I try add in Sessions to the query its no longer working.

I want all of the details of the user logged in to appear.

```
$sql= "SELECT user.username,books.bid,name,authors,edition,approve,issue,issue_book.return 
FROM user inner join issue_book 
ON user.username=issue_book.username inner join books ON issue_book.bid=books.bid WHERE 
issue_book.approve !='' and
issue_book.approve !='Yes' and  username ='$_SESSION['login_user']'
ORDER BY `issue_book`.`return` DESC";
```

The error that I am currently having is a syntax error, unexpected string content "", expecting "-" or identifier or variable or number. The issue seems to be around:

and  username ='$_SESSION['login_user']'

Answer (score 0):

change this `username ='$_SESSION['login_user']'`

to `username =$_SESSION['login_user']`

Comment: doesn't change anything the same error appears.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the thing is, you need to use the concatenate operator to concatenate the variable with the SQL query.

This should work

```
issue_book.approve !='Yes' and  username = ".$_SESSION['login_user'];
```

Refer this too - [how to use session value in sql query in php ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21778426/how-to-use-session-value-in-sql-query-in-php)

Php Concatenate  - [enter link description here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: I get this when I use your exact code: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected identifier "ORDER"

Comment: Remove the semicolon at the end and see as you have some more lines of code below

Comment: I had already done that. Gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

Assign the session to a variable in front and use it in the query like this,

```
$session_value = $_SESSION['login_user'];
$sql= "SELECT user.username, books.bid FROM user INNER JOIN issue_book ON user.usernme = issue_book.username ON user.username=issue_book.username inner join books ON issue_book.bid=books.bid WHERE issue_book.approve !='' and issue_book.approve !='Yes' and  username = ".$session_value." ORDER BY `issue_book`.`return` DESC";
```